# How many instances allowed for SQL Server 2012 Standard edition?

Tags: sql-server

I need to install another instance on my server and I need to know the number of allowed instances to be used under my license for SQL Server 2012 Standard edition.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: That probably depends on the terms of your license agreement. Even if you get an answer here, it might not apply to your specific terms. I'm afraid you cannot hope for a definite answer on SO.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 SE can be licensed using either a core or CAL model.  You will be covered for additional instances on the same machine under core licensing.  For CAL licensing, all users must have a CAL of the same or newer SQL version (can be used for any instance).  That being said, your best bet for questions regarding pricing and licensing is to contact a Microsoft sales partner or licensing expert.

Call (1-800-426-9400), Monday through Friday, 6:00 AM to 6:00 PM PST to speak directly to Microsoft licensing specialist.

Comment: thank you guys for your valuable answers , I found that the standard edition allowed to take up to 50 instances.

thank again.